# What implications does consistency have on async writes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Both Datastax Python and Java Cassandra drivers supports async writes. Both of them also allows setting consistency level. Does the consistency level have any implication whatsoever for async writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has all of the same implications as a non-async write. In fact the code for non async operations in the drivers just calls the async execute method and blocks waiting for the future to return. The futures will not be returned until the contract set by the consistency level is met or will return an error.